# Can I create a primary key and auto increment at the same time?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column I want to modify into a Primary Key and Auto Increment. It has some good values (all unique) and has some NULL values. I can't auto increment it because it isn't the primary key, and I can't make it the primary key because it hasn't been auto incremented to give the NULL some values.

How do I solve this?

Example:

```
1   |data...
2   |data...
3   |data...
NULL|data...
NULL|data...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to set those `NULL` values to unique row IDs, then you can change the row into a `PRIMARY KEY` with `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Try something like this:

```
SET @lastID = 3;  -- The highest value in your table, MAX(rowID)

UPDATE mytable
    SET rowID = (@lastID := @lastID+1)
    WHERE rowID IS NULL;
```

That should "fix" the `NULL`s and set them to values.  Then you can make the key:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
    MODIFY rowID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. For anyone else facing this issue, I just used `select max(id) into @lastID from table;` to dynamically set the initial value.

Comment: Glad I could help!  I knew there was a way to set the variable from a query, I just wasn't sure how to do it.  :-)

Comment: I figured this was a pretty common question, but was surprised it wasn't covered in the comments of the mysql documentation.

Comment: I think you can also do `SELECT @lastID := MAX(id) FROM table;`.